# ¿Cómo saltar al archivo de una función en el editor de texto Atom?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Necesito saber si existe algún paquete que pueda instalar en Atom que al posicionarme en una función o al hacer click en esta me abra el archivo al cual pertenece.

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste https://atom.io/packages? Cabe mencionar que en [ask] se indica que las preguntas deben incluir lo buscado/investigado sobre el tema.

Comment: Que yo sepa no existe aún.

Comment: https://atom.io/packages/hyperclick

Comment: Existe un paquete que se llama goto-definition, acá explican como funciona y como instalarlo, el usarlo es simple dar click derecho en la función y luego ir a definición. [Paquete Goto-Definition](https://atom.io/packages/goto-definition)